# Binding OpenCV with Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, opencv, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an app with Xamarin using opencv. For xamarin.droid there isn't problem but for the .ios i have some difficult to bind the library. I followed this guide: http://trinnguyen.com/opencv-for-xamarin-ios/ but in I can't declare methods that expect for example Mat's objects because I don't have any opencv reference .

Someone has tried to do this type of binding?